# Why does the "+" operator work in parsing string to number?

Tags: javascript

From what I have poorly remembered before, javascript tries to convert the operands to a similar type before doing the operation. However, when I tried to do the following in the console:

```
+'11111'
*'11111'
```

They produce different results - addition parses, multiplication fails. This means what I remembered was wrong. What is the exact reason that + works? I have also seen people use it in IIFEs

```
+(function() {

})()

//the same as:

;(function() {

})()
```

Comment: Besides being in the language specification, probably because the prefix `+` operator makes mathematical sense? I.e. `+123` is a valid number. `*123` isn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`+'11111'` results in the number `11111` because [unary +](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-unary-plus-operator) converts the expression on its right side to a number. But there's no such thing as "unary *", so `*'11111'` throws an error. (What would `*'11111'` even mean?)

As for the IIFEs:

```
;(function() {

})()
```

the `;`  ensures that the IIFE starts *after* the end of the previous statement. Were it not for the `;`, and the previous statement did not end with a `;`, the lack of Automatic Semicolon Insertion on the previous line could cause bugs:

```js
const arr = []

(function() {

})()
```

But using `+` without a semicolon on the previous line is not a good idea, because then the return value of the IIFE can be added or concatenated to the previous line:

```js
const arr = []

+(function() {

})()

console.log(arr);
```

If you always put semicolons at the end of statements when appropriate, then there's no need to put anything before the `(` of an IIFE:

```js
const arr = [];
(function() {
  console.log('iife');
})();
console.log(arr);
```

(If you aren't an expert, I'd recommend using semicolons, rather than relying on the slightly strange [rules of ASI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi) - they'll sometimes result in hard-to-understand bugs)

Comment: I think OP misread the IIFE case, sometimes (code-golf) `+function(){}()` is used in place of `(function(){})()`

Answer (score 1):

There is a good explanation and examples [here](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-unary-operators/) and [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-unary-operators-simple-and-useful#toc-what-is-an-unary-operator-) for JavaScript Unary Operators.

TDLR: The unary operation tries to convert anything to a number, and if it can't success it will return NaN

```
+3                                   // returns 3
+'-3'                                // returns -3
+'3.14'                              // returns 3.14
+'3'                                 // returns 3
+'0xFF'                              // returns 255
+true                                // returns 1
+'123e-5'                            // returns 0.00123
+false                               // returns 0
+null                                // returns 0
+'Infinity'                          // returns Infinity
+'infinity'                          // returns NaN
+function(val){  return val }        // returns NaN
```